# Canvas keydown events

Tags: events, canvas, key

I'm fairly new to canvas and experimenting with random functions.  I've gotten mouseClick events and now I'm trying to implement a keydown event to do something simple like change the background color.

I'm looking at a lot of keyDown event examples and am a little confused about the structured.

Is it as simple as

```
if (e.keyCode == 40) { *change background color code }
```

I'm seeing a lot of people having some false, true statements in there as well, which throws me off.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's that simple. Check if the key was pressed inside of a listener for the keydown event:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 40) {
        *change background*
    }
});
```

Alternative:

```
var keys = [];
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    keys[event.keyCode] = true;
    if (keys[40] === true) {
        *change background color*
    }
});
window.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
    keys[event.keyCode] = false;
});
```

(might be aforementioned true/false statements OP mentioned)

JSFiddle: [#1](https://jsfiddle.net/khanfused/6p41b9d1/), [#2](https://jsfiddle.net/khanfused/0pe2je5e/).